# Quaternions still have gimbal lock

Tags: math, vector, 3d, quaternions

Instead of Euler angles I moved to Quaternions to represent and process the rotation of a cube in 3D. Although it would solve gimbal lock, I'm still experiencing this issue.

My code is:

```
// p is the point to be rotated
// angles is a Vector3D representing the rotation angles

var xaxis = new Vector3D(1, 0, 0);
var yaxis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
var zaxis = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);

p = rotate(p, xaxis, angles.x);
p = rotate(p, yaxis, angles.y);
p = rotate(p, zaxis, angles.z);
```

The `rotate` functions comes from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Pseudo-code_for_rotating_using_a_quaternion_in_3D_space (translated into JavaScript).

I guess the problem is due to the fact that I still use an order of axes (`x y z`) which is the main problem of gimbal lock.

How would one implement quaternion rotation in such a way that gimbal lock is solved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quaternions are not susceptible to gimbal lock, so that's not your problem.  If your
x, y, and z angles are intended to represent something like Euler angles, the issue
is more likely that you're defining xaxis, yaxis, and zaxis relative to the original
coordinate system.  But that won't give the expected results, because after the first
rotation around xaxis, the Y and Z axes don't point in the original directions
any more, yet the next two rotations are still referenced to the original coordinate
system.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but is there perhaps a way to make the three axes independable, so that Y and Z will still point in the original directions after rotation around the X axis?

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that I'm using this in a 3D engine. Instead of using a specific order of axes I instead updated the coordinates of the cube vertexes after rotation. So e.g. it will basically first rotate on the X axis, then save the calculated points as if that were the original points. Any eventual rotations afterwards will behave as if that was the only rotation executed. Anyway, what it comes down to is that the gimbal lock has been saved with quaternions now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As you mention the gimbal lock issue arises anytime you do three consecutive rotations (such as Euler Angles) to get from an inertial coordinate frame to a body frame. This includes combining three successive quaternion rotations (through a operation called composition).

The reason why quaternions can overcome gimbal lock is that they can represent the transformation from the inertial coordinate frame to the body fixed frame in a single rotation. This is however imho the big disadvantage of quaternions - it is not physically intuitive to come up with a desired quaternion.